# VersionConflictException when downloading document

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I sometimes get a VersionConflictException when trying to download a file from Google Docs. I'm guessing this is harmless but why does this happen?

I'm using gdata-media-1.0-1.41.3.jar

```
com.google.gdata.util.VersionConflictException: Conflict
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:612)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:563)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:552)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:530)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:535)
at com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.getMediaResource(MediaService.java:234)
at com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.getMedia(MediaService.java:276)
at com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.getMedia(MediaService.java:302)
```

The code we are using is as follows:

```
DocumentListEntry entry = ... // from the feed of changed documents
MediaContent documentContent = (com.google.gdata.data.MediaContent) entry.getContent();
String uri = documentContent.getUri();
MediaContent downloadContent = new MediaContent();
downloadContent.setUri(uri);
MediaSource mediaSource = docsService.getMedia(downloadContent);
InputStream inputStream = mediaSource.getInputStream();
File file = // some file
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
try {
    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, output);
} finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
}
```

Comment: Usually we have around 100 VersionConflictException in our logs every day. It happens all day, but seem to be most frequent outside office hours!? It happens for different users and different documents.